# How to use Botan Amalgamation files and VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, encryption, botan

- Clean install of Windows XP SP3
- Install Python 2.7.2
- Extract Botan 1.10.1 to the desktop
- Run **configure.py --cc=msvc --disable-shared --gen-amalgamation**
- Copy **botan_all.h** and **botan_all.cpp** to my dev workstation
- Make a new project Win32 console project in VS2008

This gives me 102 errors ... anyone using this library?

```
#include "botan_all.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your project is a windows application and includes windows.h,  windows.h includes macros for min and max.

The solution is to define #define NOMINMAX
You can do through the project's property pages > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor definitions

Also, add  #define BOTAN_DLL in botan_all.h to avoid error at least in version 1.10.1

Comment: Thank you for your help. I skipped using Botan and went with a CryptoAPI/OpenSSL class. I can't really verify your answer so I just accept it.

Comment: I am running into the same problem (102 errors, too - at least...) an I have set it to not include any other header.It's certainly not min/max (though this was my first guess, too, and the first error, curiously, is at a std::min - just not the first occurence thereof)

Comment: What helped for me was adding `using std::min; using std::max` on botan_all.cpp right after the includes, and replacing all `std::min`, `std::max` with `min`, `max`